# Is it possible in Bash 4.0 to substring and uppercase a variable in one

Tags: bash, bash4

Given a variable `var=toucan` I can do the following:

```
echo ${var^^}
TOUCAN
echo ${var:3}
can
```

Is it possible to do something similar to `echo ${var:3^^}` to get `CAN`?

```
echo ${var:3^^}
bash: var: 3^^: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "^")
```

Comment: There are a lot of potential duplicates for this one. The answer still comes down to "no", whichever is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; bash doesn't let you combine special parameter expansions like that (for any of them, including remove-affix, value-if-null, value-if-null-or-empty, etc.) You will have to do it in two steps, or use a program outside of bash.